# sudo not working on debian

Tags: debian, sudo, users, root

Why sudo command is not working on my fresh debian installation.
I had this error after entering my root password:

> Sorry try again ..

or / and

> incorrect password attempt

EDIT : In my /etc/sudoers, I have the default content :

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I am sure that I am typing the right password.

**Update**:

When the system locks the screen, I can't log in. This is the auth log:

```
polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session8 (system bus name :1.124, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Comment: You are in the `sudo` group?

Comment: @wurtel presumably the `myuser` negates the need for that.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at the contents as you wrote that the default contents were in the file... apparently not. You *did* use `visudo` to edit it? Check `/var/log/auth.log` for hints.

Comment: I am in the sudo group and I the content of sudoers is not exatly the same (format, comments ..etc= but the configuration is the same.

Comment: No, the configuration is *not* the same, you added a line (that was my point -- i.e. configuration is not default). Again, you did use `visudo`? And have you checked `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: You need to enter your own password - not `root` with `sudo`.

Comment: I will edit my post for sudoers file. Here is auth.log `hostname sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=myuser uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=myuser rhost=  user=myuser`

Comment: According to that log, you are logged in as `myuser` (`logname=myuser`) and trying to `sudo` to `myuser` (`user=myuser`).  When using `sudo` you should be logged in with a user (that has `sudo` permissions) and temporarily become another user (eg `root`) using the user's password if `/etc/sudoers` allows.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` command requires password of current user, not `root` user.
If you wish to authorize by root password you can just use `su -`.

Comment: I know and anyway my root password is the same as "myuser" password. sudo command is not working and su - is working, this is my problem.